# Elegant way of deleting a (the row of the) cell that contains "xxx" in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sheet:

[image]

I want to delete the rows whereever the city column contains "USA". ex. the desired output is below:

[image]

My approach is to create another column at `C2:C4` with the `=isnumber(search("USA",B2))`. Then

```
for i = lastrow to 2 step -1
    If cells(i, "C") then
    Else
        rows(i).delete
    end if
next
```

This method works, but I feel is very stupid and runs very slow on large datasets. Any thoughts on achieving this elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want - assumes the data is on Sheet1 in columns `A` and `B`.

```
Sub Del_USA()
Dim c As Range

With Sheet1.Range("B:B")
    Set c = .Find("*USA*", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    
        With Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter 2, "*USA*", 7
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    
    Else
        MsgBox "USA Not Found"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it works like a charm! I understand this part pretty well `With Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter 2, "*USA*", 7
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With` but could you please explain a bit what does `c` do?

Comment: It's part of a test to ensure the text "USA" actually does exist in Column `B`.  Run the code twice & you'll see what I mean.  Also, please mark the answer as Accepted if it does what you were after.

Comment: a trivial question: why sometime the vba args/params are in `()` and sometimes are not, such as `.AutoFilter 2, "*USA*", 7` and sometimes you need to specify the arg_name `LookIn:=xlValues`

Comment: also could you please explain what is this `7` here `.AutoFilter 2, "*USA*", 7` @kevin9999

Comment: `7` is the shorthand for `LookIn:=xlValues`. This is worth a read: https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Autofilter_en.html

Comment: This is a wondeful guide! Excel's official documentation is way too simple. no where does it mention the shorthands of the operator. It's also not very convenient that those options don't show up while coding in VBA

Comment: fyi Though late to the party, you might be interested in my *MS 365* approach using the new dynamic array features via WorksheetFunction `FILTER()` @kevin9999

Answer (score 2):

**Solution via WorksheetFunction `FILTER()`**

Profiting from the new dynamic array features of *Microsoft 365* you could simply use a **formula** to filter a given range of e.g. `A2:B5`.

```
=FILTER($A$2:$B$5,ISERROR(FIND(UPPER("uSa"),UPPER($A$2:$B$5)))*(LEN($A$2:$B$5)))
```

This formula approach displays results at another spill range. -
As, however you want to **overwrite** the original source range, you'd have to code a VBA procedure like this using the same basic worksheet functionality via `Evaluate()` (see section `B`):

**Example call**

Note that `Find()` doesn't need wild cards and I adapted the following code to allow also a case insensitive search.

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    DelCrit "uSa", Sheet1.Range("A2:B5")
End Sub
```

**Procedure `DelCrit`**

```
Sub DelCrit(ExcludeTerm As String, rng As Range, Optional ByVal colNum As Long = 2)
'Auth:
    Const PATTERN$ = "=FILTER($,ISERROR(FIND(UPPER(""?""),UPPER(~)))*(LEN(~)))"
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'A) adapt formula
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim rngAddr As String: rngAddr = rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address
    Dim colAddr As String: colAddr = rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Columns(colNum).Address
    Dim MyFormula As String
    MyFormula = Replace(Replace(Replace(PATTERN, _
                "$", rngAddr), _
                "~", colAddr), _
                "?", ExcludeTerm)
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'B) get result array
    '   (2-dim matrix or "flat" 1-dim array)
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim result: result = Evaluate(MyFormula)     ' << Code evaluation
    
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'C) write result
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    rng = vbNullString
    On Error Resume Next
    rng.Resize(UBound(result), UBound(result, 2)) = result
    If Err.Number Then          ' provide for 1-dim "flat" array
        rng.Resize(1, UBound(result)) = result
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting solution.  Excel took a great step forward with the introduction of the `FILTER()` function.